# Problems with glossaries package 'see' attribute

Tags: glossaries

I'm using the [`glossaries`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries) package to define a glossary (who would have thought of that). Yesterday I came across the feature to be able to use `see={other glossary entry, another one, etc.}` which I like very much. But using this feature something funny happened. I have one central glossary file for all my documents. So I am dependent on glossaries to only include those entries from the file that I actually did use in the document. But what happens now is that all entries for which the `see` attribute is used, are included in the glossaries even though not referenced in the document.

To clarify: If I create an empty LaTeX document inserting the glossary file via `\input{glossary.tex}` those entries that have the see attribute will end up in a glossary in the document, though the document itself is completely empty.

Is this behavior meant to be? Did I miss something?

I hope someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong (if this is not meant to be).

Comment: I guess you import your glossary entries after `\makeglossaries`. You have to do this before. Note furthermore that it is generally better to use `\loadglsentries` than `\input` to import glossary entries.

Comment: Please excuse my late response, I was expecting an Email notification. Yes, that did the trick. Using \loadglsentries then immediately complained.

Comment: @mhp You should make your comment into an answer because using `\loadglsentries` seems to be what the OP was looking for.

Comment: @Torsten: Please consider registering your account, then email notification can be configured.

Comment: @mhp: Yes, please convert it to an answer. The wrong order of `\makeglossaries` and, in my case `input` lead to the trouble. `loadglsentries` does keep you from doing so because it needs to be called in the preamble.

Comment: I've made my comment an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you import your glossary entries after `\makeglossaries`. You have to do this before. Note furthermore that it is generally better to use `\loadglsentries` than `\input` to import glossary entries. Thus:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\loadglsentries{glossary.tex}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `\loadglsentries` instead of `\input` seems to do the trick for me. However, if I use `\loadglsentries` before `\makeglossaries` I get the message `! Package glossaries Error: `see' key may only be used after \makeglossaries or \makenoidxglossaries.`.

Comment: @usernumber I can confirm that. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154704/109961