# Glossaries: "see" having no effect

Tags: cross-referencing, packages, glossaries

I tried to implement the `glossaries` package in my document and it works pretty well. But when it comes to the "see" option, I'm currently facing some trouble: whether I include a `see=entry2` or not, is affecting the glossary in no way

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{entry1}{
  name=first example,
  description={\lipsum[3]},
  sort=example1,
  see=[see also]{entry2}
}

\newglossaryentry{entry2}{
  name=second example,
  description={\lipsum[4]},
  sort=example2,
}

\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{\hspace{1em}}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

This is the first \gls{entry1} for testing. 

\lipsum[2]

\medskip

And this is the second \gls{entry2} for testing. 

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

What's wrong with the above MWE?

Comment: You should get an error telling you that `see` can be used only after `\makeglossaries`. Put `\makeglossaries` before the first `\newglossaryentry` and retry.

Comment: Well I don't, but it obviously solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When going from version 3.07 to version 4.0 of `glossaries`, the author has added a check and your input, with the new version, would produce

```
! Package glossaries Error: `see' key may only be used after \makeglossaries.
```

Apparently, in the previous versions, this went under silence and `see` didn't work without any warning.

So the solution is to issue `\makeglossaries` before any `\newglossaryentry` instruction.